# Unexplained Mesh Shading Glitch Upon Rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, mesh

I’m really hoping someone can help me figure this out.

Creating a 3D asset for an upcoming livestream. Everything has been going great overall. The shading for the model looks the way it’s supposed to in the Viewport Shading preview window. The mesh looks fine, there’s no artifacts showing at all in the problem area. I’ve rendered tons of test renders and nothing was out of the ordinary. The render always looked like the Viewport Shading preview.

Everything looks great in the Viewport Shading Render preview.

[image: Render preview normal]

All of the renders looked great, just like the preview.

[image: Normal render]

I added some keyframes for the animation, went to render, and the final render images started to look like this.

[image: Glitch Render]

There are what looks like shading artifacts in the final render, over the front right tire and along the right side of the vehicle. This began immediately after adding keyframes for the animation. That’s all I did. I didn’t touch any of the settings or mess with the model in any way, other than to rotate the front tire and steering wheel. The mesh looks perfectly fine in the Viewport Shading Solid view. The machine gun cover on the right is also leaking a tiny bit of yellow light, that it wasn’t before. In the render, it looks as if the mesh somehow got deformed, but as stated, I didn’t touch the mesh at all between the normal render and the glitch renders.

Already tested by removing the dof, motion blur, and keyframes. Issue persists. A save file from 2 saves back, shows the render as normal.

If additional information is needed, please let me know. I need to get this fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: If anyone has any ideas, I'd love to hear them, so I know what not to do next time.

Went ahead and opened up an earlier save and redid the lost work. The project is back to where it was at the time of the glitch.